# NMaximize on Which Function

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have a function covering multiple cases made by using 'Which' function. Based on some parameters, the function value changes. When I plot it, I could see the function is continuous. Now I am trying to find the numerical solution by using Nmaximize on this function. Specifically, I want to find x which maximizes the value of TPo1 function below.

Here's my function TPo1.

```
TPo1[x_?NumericQ, va_?NumericQ, vb_?NumericQ, 
   pa_?NumericQ, \[Theta]_?NumericQ, pb_?NumericQ, \[Beta]_?NumericQ, 
   t_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ, m_?NumericQ, f_?NumericQ, 
   r_?NumericQ] :=  
  Which[\[Gamma]i[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= x <= 
    xs[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= 
    xmax[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] < \[Gamma]2[va, vb, 
     pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] < 
    xc[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] < 2, 
   ROS5[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t, c, m, f, 
    r], \[Gamma]i[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= 
    xs[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= x <= 
    xmax[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= \[Gamma]2[va, vb, 
     pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] < 
    xc[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] < 2, 
   ROS6[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t, c, m, f, 
    r], \[Gamma]i[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= 
    xs[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= 
    xmax[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= 
    x <= \[Gamma]2[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] < 
    xc[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] < 2,
   ROS7[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t, c, m, f, r],
   \[Gamma]i[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= x <= 
    xs[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= 
    xmax[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] < 
    xc[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= \[Gamma]2s[va, vb, 
     pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] < 2, 
   ROS8[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t, c, m, f, r],
   \[Gamma]i[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= 
    xs[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= x <= 
    xmax[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] < 
    xc[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= \[Gamma]2s[va, vb, 
     pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] < 2, 
   ROS9[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t, c, m, f, r],
   \[Gamma]i[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= 
    xs[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= 
    xmax[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= x <= 
    xc[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= \[Gamma]2s[va, vb, 
     pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <  2, 
   ROS10[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t, c, m, f, r],
   \[Gamma]i[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= 
    xs[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= 
    xmax[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] < 
    xc[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= 
    x <=  \[Gamma]2s[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] < 2, 
   ROS11[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t, c, m, f, r],
   \[Gamma]i[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= x <= 
    xs[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= 
    xmax[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] < 
    xc[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] < 
    2 <= \[Gamma]2s[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t], 
   ROS12[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t, c, m, f, r],
   \[Gamma]i[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= 
    xs[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= x <= 
    xmax[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] < 
    xc[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] < 
    2 <= \[Gamma]2s[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t], 
   ROS13[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t, c, m, f, 
    r], \[Gamma]i[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= 
    xs[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= 
    xmax[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= x <= 
    xc[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] < 
    2 <= \[Gamma]2s[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t], 
   ROS14[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t, c, m, f, r],
   \[Gamma]i[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= 
    xs[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= 
    xmax[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] < 
    xc[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= x <= 
    2 <=  \[Gamma]2s[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t], 
   ROS15[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t, c, m, f, r],
   xs[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= \[Gamma]i[va, vb, 
     pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= x <= 
    xmax[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= \[Gamma]2[va, vb, 
     pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] < 
    xc[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] < 2, 
   ROS16[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t, c, m, f, r],
   xs[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= \[Gamma]i[va, vb, 
     pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= 
    xmax[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= 
    x <= \[Gamma]2[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] < 
    xc[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] < 2, 
   ROS17[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t, c, m, f, r],
   xs[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= \[Gamma]i[va, vb, 
     pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= x <= 
    xmax[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] < 
    xc[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= \[Gamma]2s[va, vb, 
     pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <   2, 
   ROS18[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t, c, m, f, r],
   xs[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= \[Gamma]i[va, vb, 
     pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= 
    xmax[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= x <= 
    xc[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= \[Gamma]2s[va, vb, 
     pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <  2, 
   ROS19[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t, c, m, f, r],
   xs[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= \[Gamma]i[va, vb, 
     pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= 
    xmax[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] < 
    xc[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= 
    x <= \[Gamma]2s[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] < 2, 
   ROS20[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t, c, m, f, r],
   xs[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= \[Gamma]i[va, vb, 
     pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= x <= 
    xmax[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] < 
    xc[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] < 
    2 <= \[Gamma]2s[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t], 
   ROS21[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t, c, m, f, r],
   xs[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= \[Gamma]i[va, vb, 
     pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= 
    xmax[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= x <= 
    xc[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] < 
    2 <= \[Gamma]2s[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t], 
   ROS22[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t, c, m, f, r],
   xs[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= \[Gamma]i[va, vb, 
     pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= 
    xmax[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] < 
    xc[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t] <= x <= 
    2 <=  \[Gamma]2s[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t], 
   ROS23[va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t, c, m, f, r]];
```

I want to find the optimal x such that numerically maximizing the function above. Here is my trial below.

```
NMaximize[{TPo1[x, va, vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t, c, m, f, 
    r], {0 < x < 2, 10 < va < 200, 5 < vb < 200, 100 < pa < 500, 
    0.1 < \[Theta] < 1, 50 < pb < 500, 0.1 < \[Beta] < 1, 1 < t < 10, 
    50 < c < 1000, 10 < m < 50, 0 < f < 50, 0 < r < 1000}}, {x, va, 
   vb, pa, \[Theta], pb, \[Beta], t, c, m, f, r}, 
  Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"] // Quiet
```

This unfortunately gives me this error.

```
NMaximize::nnum: The function value -Null is not a number at {c,f,m,pa,pb,r,t,va,vb,x,\[Beta],\[Theta]} = {685.229,27.0992,41.5749,458.164,181.352,595.089,9.13557,127.261,138.32,1.72278,0.353285,0.578122}.
```

Would the NMaximize not work at 'Which' function? Could I ask what the issue here is?

Comment: It should work. Probably needs default `True` case for `Which`, just check what it evaluates to at these values from the message, they don't correspond to any inequality present.

Comment: Might be evaluation semantics since `Which` is really a programmatic (rather than mathematical) construct. I will suggest rewriting that function instead using `Piecewise`.

Comment: Are you sure your functions _(e.g ROS5, ROS6,... etc. which, along with other constants, you haven't provided definitions for in the question so we cannot reproduce the issue)_ are returning values properly? If you are not returning using `Return`, but using last-line / expression return and have a semicolon, then you will get Nulls. e.g if `f[x_] := (
  Print["hey!"];
  x^2;)` then `InputForm[f[2]]` is `Null` but if `g[x_] := (
  Print["hey!"];
  Return[x^2])`  then `InputForm[g[2]]` is 4.

Comment: Thank you all for replying my question. I figured out why this happens. Yes it is related to the function not returning the numerical value. Although I change which function to Piecewise as Daniel suggested, I think it will work also for which function since the core issue was whether it returns a number or not. Thanks everyone.